# Load image from POST URL using glide in android

Tags: android, android-glide, imagedownload

We need to make a rest service call of type `POST` to download an image,
this api expects `Multipart` type in the request body.

Is it possible to use glide here to make such an api call to download the image?

i know that glide can be used with URLs which are of type GET and directly returns the images as shown below

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://moodle.htwchur.ch/pluginfile.php/124614/mod_page/content/4/example.jpg")
        .override(300, 200)
        .into(resizeImage);
```

Comment: Tha's too much for `Glide`.

Comment: Followed the answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48828386/932044
It worked for me